# Why we can omit $o(n^{-1})$ inside limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\exp\left(\frac{n}{2}\ln\left(1+\frac{2x}{n}+o(n^{-1})\right)\right)\longrightarrow e^x$$

How to prove that one can omit $o(n^{-1})$ and previous steps?(Do I call it right?)

What books with proofs about solving limits you may recommend? (I just don't want to "reinvent the wheel" in this type of proofs.)

1)$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}=e^x,\mbox{ by definition of exp}$$
1')$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{z}\right)^{z}=e^x,\mbox{ by ? (limit with real or complex base)}$$
(real case may be found [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B))

2)$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{2x}{n}\right)^{n/2}=e^x,\mbox{ by ?}$$
3)$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{2x}{n}+o(n^{-1})\right)^{n/2}=e^x,\mbox{ by ?}$$
(i think it will be enough fir me to have links to any suitable theorems in books instead of question marks)
Any comments about proofs are highly appreciated!

Comment: I'd write
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{2x}{n}+o(n^{-1})\right)=\frac{2x}{n}+o(n^{-1})$$
and go from there.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Is it equality as sets? I believe that iterated application of the theorem "limit of continuous function" gives the solution here.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Sorry, I was wrong in previous comment. How to prove that statament?